# C++ How can I calculate the sum of a running total of fractions?

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to add 1/2^1 +1/2^2 + 1/2^3....1/2^n (user enters nth power). It should display the fractions (1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8....) then find their sum and display the total sum at the end (ex: 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 = .125)
It works when the user enters 5, but any other number displays the wrong total. I get sum greater than 1, which is incorrect. How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int denom,              // Denominator of a particular term
        finalDenom,         // Denominator of the final term
        nthTerm;            // Nth term run
    double sum = 0.0;          // Accumulator that adds up all terms in the series
    char repeat;

    do
    {
        cout << "This program sums the series 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^3 + . . . + 1/2^n\n";
        cout << "What should n be in the final term (between numbers 2 and 10)? ";
        cin >> finalDenom;

        nthTerm = 0;
        for (denom = 2; nthTerm <= (finalDenom - 1); denom *= 2)
        {
            cout << "1/" << denom;
            ++nthTerm;

            if (denom != finalDenom)
            {
                cout << " + ";
            }
            else if (denom == finalDenom)
            {
                cout << " = ";
            }
            sum += pow(denom, -1);
        }

        cout << sum << endl << endl << endl;

        cout << "Do you wish to compute another series? ";
        cin >> repeat;
        repeat = toupper(repeat);
    } while ((repeat == 'Y'));


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: `And `sum += pow(denom, -1);` is too much: just do `sum += 1.0/denom;`

Comment: @BaummitAugen: right! I read **2 but that cannot be done in C. Sorry...

Comment: At a guess, it works for the first one and doesn't if you compute another series?

Comment: You need to put `nthTerm` (your iteration counter) instead of `denom` in your `if else` statements.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and didn't get any error when I debugged it. It looks like you edited the code but I don't see any difference.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: It looks like that's the problem. It works for the first run but not another series.

Comment: You confuse n (count of terms) with 2^n (denominator of that term). You could put the " = " output with the sum. You do not reset the initial values for a second loop. Also you don't need to compute pow each time, since you could just accumulate that value with *= 0.5 (although that last point is irrelevant for n=10)

Comment: If you don't use `nthTerm` outside the while loop, why not remove the outer level declaration and change `nthTerm = 0;` to `int nthTerm = 0;`? You can also do the same with `denom` and `for (int denom = ...`

Comment: Why does it feel like this should be something like `(2**n-1)/(2**n)`

Comment: This is a very odd question/answer pair to bounty 500 as exemplary...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iterations counter is not `denom`, it is `nthTerm`. Therefore, your if else statements should be checking `finalDenom` against the `nthTerm` and not `denom`.

Also, you are seeing results above 1 because: You probably tested your code in continues executions (using your do while loop) without resetting your `sum` variable to zero on each execution.

Also as user Jean mentioned in the comment, `sum += 1.0/denom;` is enough.
This should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int denom,              // Denominator of a particular term
        finalDenom,         // Denominator of the final term
        nthTerm;            // Nth term run
    double sum = 0.0;          // Accumulator that adds up all terms in the series
    char repeat;

    do
    {
        cout << "This program sums the series 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^3 + . . . + 1/2^n\n";
        cout << "What should n be in the final term (between numbers 2 and 10)? ";
        cin >> finalDenom;

        sum = 0;
        nthTerm = 0;

        for (denom = 2; nthTerm < finalDenom; denom *= 2)
        {
            cout << "1/" << denom;
            ++nthTerm;

            if (nthTerm != finalDenom)
                cout << " + ";
            else 
                cout << " = ";

            sum += 1.0 / denom;
        }

        cout << sum << endl << endl;

        cout << "Do you wish to compute another series? ";
        cin >> repeat;

        repeat = toupper(repeat);

    } while (repeat == 'Y');

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
This program sums the series 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^3 + . . . + 1/2^n
What should n be in the final term (between numbers 2 and 10)? 6
1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 + 1/64 = 0.984375

Do you wish to compute another series? y
This program sums the series 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^3 + . . . + 1/2^n
What should n be in the final term (between numbers 2 and 10)? 5
1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 = 0.96875

Do you wish to compute another series? y
This program sums the series 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^3 + . . . + 1/2^n
What should n be in the final term (between numbers 2 and 10)? 4
1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 = 0.9375

Do you wish to compute another series? y
This program sums the series 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^3 + . . . + 1/2^n
What should n be in the final term (between numbers 2 and 10)? 3
1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 = 0.875

Do you wish to compute another series? n
```

As a further note, you should add some validation of whatever the users input to the program, at least that the final term is in the range [2,10].

Comment: Don't post images of text results.  You can easily copy and paste the text into the answer.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I tried that and it looked messy. I will do it anyway just for you :)

Comment: @softengstu Glad we were able to help. Next time use your debugger properly :)

Comment: @FirstStep: I used the built in debugger that comes with Visual Studio Express and it didn't show any errors. Is there another debugger I could use that would catch such an error?

Comment: This may have been a little too much help on homework. For posting the text output, put it in its own code block (indent 4), and it will be formatted exactly as it appears.

Comment: @softengstu Maybe I should have mentioned that these are logical errors and not syntax errors. No compiler/debugger would catch those for you. You needed to step through your code and watch the values of each variable. Using F-10 on Visual Studio.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I will go ahead and do that :) Thanks

Comment: `...if (nthTerm == finalDenom)...` We don't really need that, right?

Comment: @Bob__ I think you are right. My bad. Got overwhelmed by issues lol

Comment: @FirstStep I'll try F10 on Visual Studio next time. Thanks :)

Comment: @Bob__ Oh no I don't, definitely. Thanks for fixing / improving it :)

Answer (score 2):

I think that your approach is inefficient and imprecise. This is a geometric progression. The sum of this sequence could be found with a single expression.

[image]

Just substitute r with 1/2 in this formula.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned your problem is in the if conduction.However I would throw it away completely.

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int denom,              // Denominator of a particular term
        finalDenom,         // Denominator of the final term
        nthTerm;            // Nth term run
    double sum = 0.0;          // Accumulator that adds up all terms in the series
    char repeat;

    do
    {
        cout << "This program sums the series 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^3 + . . . + 1/2^n\n";
        cout << "What should n be in the final term (between numbers 2 and 10)? ";
        cin >> finalDenom;
        denom=2;
        for (nthTerm = 0; nthTerm < finalDenom; nthTerm++)

        {
            denom*=2;

            cout << "1/" << denom;
            cout << " + ";                      
            sum += pow(denom, -1);
        }

        cout << " = ";

        cout << sum << endl << endl << endl;

        cout << "Do you wish to compute another series? ";
        cin >> repeat;
        repeat = toupper(repeat);
    } while ((repeat == 'Y'));


    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
This program sums the series 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^3 + . . . + 1/2^n
What should n be in the final term (between numbers 2 and 10)? 1
1/4 +  = 0.25


Do you wish to compute another series? y
This program sums the series 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^3 + . . . + 1/2^n
What should n be in the final term (between numbers 2 and 10)? 2
1/4 + 1/8 +  = 0.625


Do you wish to compute another series? y
This program sums the series 1/2^1 + 1/2^2 + 1/2^3 + . . . + 1/2^n
What should n be in the final term (between numbers 2 and 10)? 4
1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + 1/32 +  = 1.09375


Do you wish to compute another series? n

Exit code: 0 (normal program termination)
```

Answer (score -1):

I do belive it is easier to have a value `Something`. Half it each loop, or `somthing = 1/pow(2,n)`(1 divided by 2 to the power of n). Then sum is 1-`something`. Less code is always nice. :)

Another improvement is:

```
for (denom = 2; nthTerm < finalDenom; denom *= 2)
    {
        cout << "1/" << denom;
        ++nthTerm;

            cout << " + ";

        sum += 1.0 / denom;
    }
    Cout << "=";
```

And minor tweaking to this code

So my code would be

```
for (denom = 2; nthTerm < finalDenom; denom *= 2)
{
    cout << "1/" << denom;
    ++nthTerm;

        cout << " + ";
}
Cout << "=";
Sum = 1 - (pow(2,finalDenom));
```

If you think this i a bad answer, explain why so I can improve my answer.

Comment: `^` does not mean exponentiation in C++

Comment: I know. But that is easily fixed. I diddnt have time to look up the function

Comment: Fixed now I think

Comment: No this definitely is not fixed.

Comment: @Barry what is not fixed?

Comment: This isn't the place for guess-and-check. Try to actually compile and run your code.